# How can I loop with dates?

Tags: r

Assume I have following dates:

```
Start <- c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-02-02"),as.Date("2020-06-06"))
End <- c(as.Date("2028-01-01", as.Date("2026-02-02"), as.Date("2025-06-06"))
```

And I would like to have a vector with all dates in a date format (%Y-%m-%d):

```
Vec <- c()      

for (i in 1:3){
  Vec <- c(Vec, seq.Date(Start[i],End[i], by ="year"))
}
```

Unfortunately, the dates don't get stored in a date format. How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the corresponding dates in 'Start', 'End' vector and get the `seq`, specify the `by` in `MoreArgs`.  This would create a `list` of sequence of `Date`s which can be converted to a single `vector` with `c` using `do.call`

```
do.call(c, Map(seq, MoreArgs  = list(by = 'year'), Start, End))
#[1] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01" "2025-01-01" "2026-01-01" "2027-01-01" "2028-01-01" "2020-02-02"
#[11] "2021-02-02" "2022-02-02" "2023-02-02" "2024-02-02" "2025-02-02" "2026-02-02" "2020-06-06" "2021-06-06" "2022-06-06" "2023-06-06"
#[21] "2024-06-06" "2025-06-06"
```

#### data

```
Start <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-06-06"))
End <- as.Date(c("2028-01-01", "2026-02-02", "2025-06-06"))
```

NOTE: We don't have to wrap `as.Date` on each element as these are vectorized and can be applied once

Answer (score 1):

```
as.Date(unlist(mapply(seq.Date,Start,End,by="year")),origin = "1970-01-01 UTC")
```